# Getting the List of Child Nodes from within a HTML Tag using PHP

Tags: php, dom

I am currently using the PHP DOM to get the BODY tag from HTML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($HTML);    
$body = preg_replace("/.*<body[^>]*>|<\/body>.*/si", "", $HTML);
```

The above code completely gives me the html from the body tag for a given HTML.

Can I get the HTML tags with `$body` as an array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks. I actually missed it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, I would use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) - it will make your solution a lot more reliable and cleaner to use.

This should get your headed in the right direction (I'm not writing the solution for you, sorry):

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://google.com");
$dom = new DOMdocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query("//*");


foreach ($elements as $element) {

        echo "<h1>". $element->nodeName. "</h1>";
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                echo "<h2>".$node->nodeName. "</h2>";
                echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I would do it with DOM. I have edited my code above. Can you give me an example...